# Check existance of layout variable?

Tags: conditionals, template-layouts, layout-variables

Is it possible to do something like the following (which doesn't work).

```
{if layout:contents}
    {layout:contents}
{if:else}
    404!
{/if}
```

thanks!

:: ed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{layout:contents}` is no regular layout variable (it will always contain the entire contents of the template in which the `{layout="template_group/template"}` tag appeared), which is why I suspect your code sample doesn't work.

But all other layout variables should work just fine as conditionals, as in your code sample.